# How to work on behalf of manager?

Tags: work-environment, manager, leadership, teamwork

My manager is out on holiday. I need to work on his behalf. What are the best way to motivate team members who are peers. How to add value during his absence.

Comment: why downvote please provide comment so that I can edit?

Comment: How about doing what your manager does?

Comment: @Dawny33 I don't know all the things that manager is doing. But I think I need to ask him.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to settle old scores.

Comment: If your manager asked you to fill in for him, didn't he tell you what you have to do?

Comment: VTC. This is something you ask your manager or, really, something you would know after working for him for some time. We can't possibly begin to guess at your duties during his absence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have been given the managers job while he is away on holiday, you're not normally expected to do anything except handle emergency situations where authority is needed. Apart from that you just keep things ticking over until your manager returns.

Motivating peers and 'adding value' is not your role. You shouldn't make any changes.

What you should do is make good notes on anything that your manager might need to know about, keep a solid paper trail on any issues that arrive, and if necessary liaise with higher authority if you cannot handle something or need clarification.

Comment: This ia the most specific answer.